# JasperServer Documentation for domain creation + Adhoc reports

Tags: jasper-reports, domain-driven-design, jasperserver

I recently buy license for the JasperServer 4.7 version. Now according to my business requirements I need to generate report using creating domains in the JasperServer.

I looked in the premium documentation of JasperServer also, but I am not getting any descent explanations of Jasper Domain + Creation of Adhoc reports from these Domain..

Can anybody tell me where to look for all in our explanation of JasperServer Domain creation + Adhoc Report creation from Domain. I may be looking in wrong direction.. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JasperReports Server User Guide there is a chapter on creating domains and another for working with the ad hoc editor. It's under "User Documentation" on the Jaspersoft support website (http://support.jaspersoft.com). Did you have a specific question?